# Access forbidden when trying to submit form in php

Tags: php, html, xampp

I am new to php. I have some lab work that I needed to do at home. A problem has to do something very simple, just to display the squared number in another php page.. But that is not happening. I have been struggling to fix this for days. I rememeber when using xampp in old days I did not have this issue. 
Every time I try to submit the form I get this:

```html
Access forbidden!
You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 403
127.0.0.1
Apache/2.4.33 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.0g PHP/7.2.4
```

I try other programs like easyPHP or wampp.. still same issue.. This is the code:

```css
//prelucrare.php
<?php
$a = $_POST[‘a’];
echo $a * $a;
?>
```

```html
//index.php
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form action=”http://localhost:80/prelucrare.php” method=”post”>
    <input type=”text” name=”a”><br>
    <button type=”submit”>Square it</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And my httpd-xampp.conf file:

```html
#
# XAMPP settings
#

<IfModule env_module>
    SetEnv MIBDIRS "C:/xampp/php/extras/mibs"
    SetEnv MYSQL_HOME "\\xampp\\mysql\\bin"
    SetEnv OPENSSL_CONF "C:/xampp/apache/bin/openssl.cnf"
    SetEnv PHP_PEAR_SYSCONF_DIR "\\xampp\\php"
    SetEnv PHPRC "\\xampp\\php"
    SetEnv TMP "\\xampp\\tmp"
</IfModule>

#
# PHP-Module setup
#
LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/php7ts.dll"
LoadFile "C:/xampp/php/libpq.dll"
LoadModule php7_module "C:/xampp/php/php7apache2_4.dll"

<FilesMatch "\.php$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.phps$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-source
</FilesMatch>

#
# PHP-CGI setup
#
#<FilesMatch "\.php$">
#    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php-cgi
#</FilesMatch>
#<IfModule actions_module>
#    Action application/x-httpd-php-cgi "/php-cgi/php-cgi.exe"
#</IfModule>


<IfModule php7_module>
    PHPINIDir "C:/xampp/php"
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_module>
    AddType text/html .php .phps
</IfModule>

ScriptAlias /php-cgi/ "C:/xampp/php/"
<Directory "C:/xampp/php">
    AllowOverride None
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/xampp/cgi-bin">
    <FilesMatch "\.php$">
        SetHandler cgi-script
    </FilesMatch>
    <FilesMatch "\.phps$">
        SetHandler None
    </FilesMatch>
</Directory>

<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/xampp">
    <IfModule php7_module>
     <Files "status.php">
      php_admin_flag safe_mode off
     </Files>
    </IfModule>
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
</Directory>

<IfModule alias_module>
    Alias /licenses "C:/xampp/licenses/"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/licenses">
        Options +Indexes
        <IfModule autoindex_color_module>
            DirectoryIndexTextColor  "#000000"
            DirectoryIndexBGColor "#f8e8a0"
            DirectoryIndexLinkColor "#bb3902"
            DirectoryIndexVLinkColor "#bb3902"
            DirectoryIndexALinkColor "#bb3902"
        </IfModule>
        Require local
        ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
   </Directory>

    Alias /phpmyadmin "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin/"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Require local
        ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
    </Directory>

    Alias /webalizer "C:/xampp/webalizer/"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/webalizer">
        <IfModule php7_module>
      <Files "webalizer.php">
       php_admin_flag safe_mode off
      </Files>
        </IfModule>
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Require local
        ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Does **http://localhost:80/prelucrare.php** is a valid directory ?

Comment: And also does your php code is written inside that php file ?

Comment: I changed the path to action=”http://localhost:80/lab3.1/prelucrare.php” which should work.. but not working.

Comment: place project folder c/xampp/htdocs

Comment: @RahulShrivastava im not that new to php. All paths are fine. My folder is in htdocs. The form shows, but when I submit it, I get that error.

Comment: check your firewall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
//prelucrare.php
<?php
$a = $_POST['a'];
$b = $a * $a;
echo $b;
?>

<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form action="prelucrare.php" method="POST">
<input type="number" name="a"><br>
<button type="submit">Square it</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The above code works perfectly. Please update your code and try again.

Comment: I suggest you to retype the code again and make sure the **quotes (" ")** are formatted correctly.